# conflict if setInterval's running

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, slider, setinterval

l didn't managed to find a way to script : if the user pressed the `next` button, stop `autoplay`, else : continue `autoplay`and keep showing `pause` button.

Thank you. :)

```
$(function() {
var timer;
function autoplay() {
    timer = setInterval(function() {
        $('#next-icon').click();
    }, 5000);
};

$('#prev-icon, #next-icon').click(function() {
    switch (this.id) {
        case 'prev-icon':
            $('#pause-icon').hide(); $('#play-icon').show(); 
            clearInterval(timer);
            break;
        case 'next-icon': 
            $('#pause-icon').hide(); $('#play-icon').show(); 
            clearInterval(timer);
            break;
    }
}); });
```

Comment: Where and how do you declare `timer`? Where and how do you call `autoplay`? What exactly happens instead of what you want? Where’s your HTML? How does this relate to sliders?

Comment: Does autoplay get called more than once, probably need to add protection if the timer is already running.

Comment: Here is just a small part of the script. timer is declared above (not in what l give you indeed). Autoplay is called when we press 'play-icon'. So  if play icon was pressed and autoplay's running, how disabled clearInterval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way :

```
    $(function() {
var timer;
function autoplay() {
        timer = setInterval(function() {
            $('#next-icon').trigger('click', true);
        }, 5000);
    };

$('#prev-icon, #next-icon').click(function(event, play) {
    switch (this.id) {
        case 'prev-icon':
            $('#pause-icon').hide(); $('#play-icon').show();
            clearInterval(timer);
            break;
        case 'next-icon':
            if (play) {
                    setInterval(timer);
                } else {
                    $('#pause-icon').hide(); $('#play-icon').show(); clearInterval(timer);
                }
            break;
    }
});
});
```